# How to implement Doctrine NotifyPropertyChanged in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, listener

Can anyone tell me how to implement [Doctrine NotifyPropertyChanged](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#notify) in Symfony?
I have implemented this code in an Entity that will notify about is changes. But how to add listener for these changes in another Entity?

I mean I want to handle this situation: Entity Book has oneToMany to Authors. When something is being changed in a partcular Author, I want to react on it in a Book Entity. So I have implemented NotifyPropertyChanged in Author. In a setter I invoke notifications, but how to add this listener to a Book entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your use case is a little bit different: the ǸotifyPropertyChanged` is usefull to tell Doctrine your entity changed. By default, Doctrine2 will iterate over all properties and compare them (so that's "automatic"). IMO, drop it. Only use case I see for it right now are some very specific cases were using the default policy would cost too much.

Another way to do would be to use some [lifecycle events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html). Changing other entities from a `preUpdate` or `postUpdate` is *notoriously* difficult. Doctrine already started calculting the "changeset", what to persist to DB, and there's no easy way to add another entity to it.

Since you are ok writing some code inside the setters, the easier path is something like this:

```
class Author
{
    public function setName($name)
    {
         // ...

         // for each setter, call onChanged
         $this->onChange();
    }

    private function onChange()
    {
         foreach ($this->books as $book) {
             // maybe call some method on your books, like onAuthorChanged() ?
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: So simple, nice and clean. Thank you very much!!! :) Worked like a charm!